# Ansible ssh connection fails with "Failed to login: Connection refused"

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have one esxi host. I need to get some data for which i need to have linux on the same host. So i reboot the host with liveboot with rhel7.4. Perform some operations and then again i reboot the host with local boot.
So the problem is when the second boot has happened im not able to perform the tasks it is failing for ssh connection as follows

```
"stderr_lines": [
    "Failed to login: Connection refused: The remote service is not running, OR is overloaded, OR a firewall is rejecting connections."
]
```

Login credential for both the os is same.
If i skip the middle reboot for linux os no error is occurred.

After each reboot i keep one check task as follow

```
- name: Wait for system to boot up
  local_action: wait_for host="{{ host_name }}" port=22 state=started delay=25 timeout=3600
  become: False
```

This is my ansible.cfg file

```
[defaults]
host_key_checking=False

[paramiko-connection]
record_host_keys=False

[ssh_connection]
ssh_args = -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null
```

Am i missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

You are using ssh master sessions...

> -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s

...but you are connecting to the same host (same name and same ip) after a reboot which changes the underlying OS, so most probably with a change of host keys between the two OS. This is a perfect situation to get an existing master session hanging.

I would first disable ssh master session and see if it solves your issue. If it does and you still want to take advantage of master sessions for performance, you can re-enable them and perform a master session cleanup on the localhost right after you initiate the reboot. Simply remove the socket file in dir declared as ssh `ControlPath`

Comment: How can i do cleanup in middle of playbook. I tred adding this task after reboot. rm -rf ~/.ansible/cp/* . But then also it is failing.

Comment: Did removing the master session fixed your problem (e.g. is it only failing now that you are trying to cleanup master sessions) ? Did you check that sshd was running on the second OS you are booting ?